# hyperlink in table of beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am preparing a slide in beamer. One page of my slides is a table. I would like to use other pages to explain the table, I am thinking of adding sth like hyperlinks, if I click a cell of a table, then it goes to the explanation page, and it can also go back, which tool/package can I do it? Can someone show me an example? Thanks

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Something like this!  Here only `tikz` package is used to assure that the return button is located at the same place on the explanation page. Every beamer page that has links should have a label (main, here, there in this example), then use the following command at proper locations.

```
\hyperlink{destination label}{\beamerreturnbutton{Go or Back or any text}};
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[label=main]{Main}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
{\hyperlink{here}{\beamerreturnbutton{Go1}}}& aaa  &  bbb \\ \hline
ccc & ddd & {\hyperlink{there}{\beamerreturnbutton{Go2}}}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,label=here]{Explanation 1}
Some explanation here for the first GO at top left cell.
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
\hyperlink{main}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile,label=there]{Explanation 2}
Some explanation there for the second GO at lower right cell..
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]() at (current page.south east){%
\hyperlink{main}{\beamerreturnbutton{Back}}};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Jesse, I tried the example, it works well exept there is no back button. I cannot find the problem.

Comment: OK, need to compile twice to render the position correctly. If problem still persists, try shift=(0cm,0cm) first and the button should be located at lower right corner of your beamer page. This means the origin is located at the lower right (south east) corner of the beamer page. Adjust shift=(negative, positive) (i.e., 3rd quadrant) to make the button show up.